# Escape character

Tags: php, string, var

I have this function :

```
<?php
function getmypost($number)
    {
        query_posts('p=1828');
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        the_title('<h1>', '</h1>');
        the_content();
        endwhile;
    }
?>
```

I need to make the 1828 as a variable
I have tried this:

```
    query_posts('\'p='. $number .'\'');
```

But it does not work. What would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly

```
query_posts('p='.$number);
```

should work.

If you need a single quote `'` in the string you'd escape the `'`

```
query_posts('p=\''.$number.'\'');
```

or using double quotes (more elegant, and you can put the variable straight in. Dominik already suggested this in his answer)

```
query_posts("p='$number'");
```

Comment: ok, it work.. byt i need more explaination.... inside the () there must be the '' the same as the delimiter... how can it work ?

Comment: you could also use query_posts("p=$number");

Comment: or `("p={$number}")` which would also work if you have a more complex variable name, such as `("p={$numbers[$index]['foo']->value}")`

Comment: This works because it is essentially getting changed to p=valueofnumberhere. What you had was before: query_posts('\'p='. $number .'\''); was getting changed to 'p=valueofnumberhere' (notice how your value has extra quotes in it). If you modified what you had query_posts('p='. $number .''); it would work as well, although the extra .'' at the end is unnecessary.

Comment: @marc-andre: You have no delimiters in your example. The ' that you see are the marks of a string in PHP: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
query_posts("'p=$number'");
```