# Simple compression algorithm - how to avoid marker-strings?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, compression

I was trying to come up with a string compression algorithm for plaintext, e.g.

```
AAAAAAAABB -> A@8BB
```

where n symbols y are written out like

```
y@n
```

The problem is: what if I need to compress the string "A@8" ? That would confuse the decompression algorithm into thinking that the original input was "AAAAAAAA" instead of just "A@8".

How can I solve this problem? I was thinking of using a "marker" character instead of the @, but what if I wanted the algorithm to work with binary data? There is no marker character that can be used in that case I suppose

Comment: You can interleave [counts and non-repeated or repeated characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PackBits). (With messages constituted of individual bits, this need a number representation that allows detecting the end of each number.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10646166/5293824): you could represent each `@` in the source by `@@`.
Everytime you encounter an `@`, you look one character ahead and find either a number (repeat previous character) or another `@` (its literally `@`).

A variant would be encoding each `@` as `@@1`, which would fit nicely into your current scheme and allows encoding n consecutive `@` as `@@n`.

Comment: An alphabet with only two characters (`but what if I wanted the algorithm to work with binary sequences?`) doesn't easily allow for escaping.

Comment: I've read _binary_ as _binary data_ (as opposed to _text_). You're right: with only two character, escaping wouldn't be a good option.

Comment: Oh sorry I meant "binary data", not really a sequence of 1s and 0s

Comment: @greybeard: It's beside the point, but an alphabet with only two characters *can* use escaping -- just use a multi-character escape sequence.  E.g. `0` = 0, `10` = 1, `11` = "repeat count follows in some known format"