# What do we mean by contextually autoescaping?

Tags: web, escaping, xss

While reading about the [Closure Templates](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/) I encountered the following statement:

> Closure Templates are contextually autoescaped to reduce the risk of XSS.

As far as I know escaping is removing ambiguity in the input string as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10646166/867461).

I am not sure what really that means, perhaps an explanation with real world example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's more detail on security and autoescaping at [this](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/security) page of the Closure Templates documentation. In particular, look at the example given [here](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/security#example).

You will see that an input, `{$x}` is escaped differently depending on where it is to be inserted in the template output (e.g. in HTML, JavaScript, CSS etc.) This is what is meant by *contextual* (i.e. context-dependent) autoescaping.

As described in the documentation:

> - When `{$x}` appeared inside HTML text, we entity-encoded it (< → `&lt;`).
> - When `{$x}` appeared inside a URL or as a CSS quantity, we rejected it because it had a protocol `javascript:` that was not `http` or `https`, and instead output a safe value `#zSoyz`. Had `{$x}` appeared in the query portion of a URL, we would have percent-encoded it instead of rejecting it outright (< → %3C).
> - When `{$x}` appeared in JavaScript, we wrapped it in quotes (if not already inside quotes) and escaped HTML special characters (< → \x3c).
> - When `{$x}` appeared inside CSS quotes, we did something similar to JavaScript, but using CSS escaping conventions (< → \3c ).
>
> The malicious output was defanged.