# What can you use instead of tick marks ' in PHP?

Tags: php, excel, cell, phpexcel, formulas

I am trying to set the value of a cell in an Excel spreadsheet to a formula that references a worksheet and has several parameters to it.  My formula is:

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet1'!AY:AY,'Sheet1'!J:J, "Q1", 'Sheet1'!M:M, "Extensions", 'Sheet1'!AW:AW, "NP")+SUMIFS('Sheet1'!AY:AY,'Sheet1'!J:J, "Q1", 'Sheet1'!M:M, "Extensions", 'Sheet1'!AW:AW, "PHBO")+SUMIFS('Sheet1'!AY:AY,'Shee1'!J:J, "Q1", 'Sheet1'!M:M, "Extensions", 'Sheet1'!AW:AW, "PR", 'Sheet1'!AN:AN, "Both")+SUMIFS('Sheet1'!AY:AY,'Sheet1'!J:J, "Q1", 'Sheet1'!M:M, "Extensions", 'Sheet1'!AW:AW, "PR", 'Sheet1'!AN:AN, "Area")
```

My PHP is:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1)
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'XXX');
```

Where XXX = the formula above.  The problem is because of the ' and " marks in the formula I get errors.

Comment: you can escape the quotes `$foo = 'Something\'s funny';`

Comment: Related: [What does it mean to escape a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646142/what-does-it-mean-to-escape-a-string)

Comment: You need to learn about PHP strings properly: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?PHP
$stmt = <<<EOF
=SUMIFS('Sheet1'!AY:AY,'Sheet1'!J:J, "Q1", 'Sheet1'!M:M, "Extensions", 'Sheet1'!AW:AW, "NP")+SUMIFS('Sheet1'!AY:AY,'Sheet1'!J:J, "Q1", 'Sheet1'!M:M, "Extensions", 'Sheet1'!AW:AW, "PHBO")+SUMIFS('Sheet1'!AY:AY,'Shee1'!J:J, "Q1", 'Sheet1'!M:M, "Extensions", 'Sheet1'!AW:AW, "PR", 'Sheet1'!AN:AN, "Both")+SUMIFS('Sheet1'!AY:AY,'Sheet1'!J:J, "Q1", 'Sheet1'!M:M, "Extensions", 'Sheet1'!AW:AW, "PR", 'Sheet1'!AN:AN, "Area")
EOF;

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1)
        ->setCellValue('B2', $stmt);
?>
```

Assigns your String to the variable $stmt then uses that variable in your function. This allows for the ' and " to be read as characters in the string instead of being read by the interpreter to break the sting.

Comment: When I open up the Excel spreadsheet it shows the formula as:  =SUMIFS($sheet0.AY:AY,$sheet0.J:J, "Q1", $sheet0.M:M, "Extensions", $sheet0.AW:AW, "NP")+SUMIFS($sheet0.AY:AY,$sheet0.J:J, "Q1", $sheet0.M:M, "Extensions", $sheet0.AW:AW, "PHBO")+SUMIFS($sheet0.AY:AY,$sheet0.J:J, "Q1", $sheet0.M:M, "Extensions", $sheet0.AW:AW, "PR", $sheet0.AN:AN, "Both")+SUMIFS($sheet0.AY:AY,$sheet0.J:J, "Q1", $sheet0.M:M, "Extensions", $sheet0.AW:AW, "PR", $sheet0.AN:AN, "Area")   Any idea why it is getting changes when saved?

Comment: While testing it i only assigned and echoed the variable. So it should work for passing the string to your function as it is. Does the php interpreter error or does it just leave that charcter in the excel sheet?

Comment: no error, just changes the ! to . and adds the $ to the formula.

Comment: Try Chaning the HEREDOC declaration to a NOWDOC, $stmt=<<<'EOF'

Comment: Nope! But I do appreciate all your help, you've gotten me closer. I'll keep trying different things with it.