# Why does '\n' output an extra blank line in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python3 `print('\n')` will generate an extra blank line. Could someone make a brief explanation about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean to escape a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646142/what-does-it-mean-to-escape-a-string)

Comment: This is a good question, should not have been downvoted

Answer (score 2):

In [the documentation for `print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) it is stated that:

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like `str()` does and written to the stream, separated by `sep` and followed by `end`.

The default value for `end` is `'\n'`, so Python *first* prints the supplied `'\n'` and *then* `end` which equals `'\n'` too; that's why you see two blank lines.

Change the default value if you don't want that:

```
print('\n', end='')
```

Note that this also applies to Python 2.x's `print` statement, it also writes `'\n'` at the end. You can change the behavior there by appending a comma character.

Comment: Rather than `print('\n', end='')`, I'd suggest just using `print()`.