# How to insert datepicker into the database in php

Tags: php, jquery, sql, datepicker

I'm having a trouble of inserting my date & time in my database. I used jquery datepicker and for the time I used a select options tag so I just need them to be inserted into the database. 
This is my date table:

**DATABASE:**

`CREATE TABLE`date_tbl`(`
date`varchar(30) NOT NULL,`
time`varchar(30) NOT NULL,`
ordertype`int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <h5 class="control-label" style="font-family:Lucida Calligraphy;margin-left: -15px">Date:</h5>
    <input type="text" name="datepicker" class="form-control" placeholder='Select date' id="datepicker" style="margin-left: -15px"/>
    <script>
        $(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        });
        });
    </script>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <h5 for="inputDate" class="control-label" style="font-family:Lucida Calligraphy;margin-left: -15px">Time: </h5>
    <select type="text" name="time" id="time" class="form-control">
        <option>Select time</option>
        <option>08:00 AM</option>
        <option>09:00 AM</option>
        <option>10:00 AM</option>
        <option>11:00 AM</option>
        <option>01:00 PM</option>
        <option>02:00 PM</option>
        <option>03:00 PM</option>
        <option>04:00 PM</option>
        <option>05:00 PM</option>
     </select>
  </div>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
   include('db.php');
   if(isset($_POST['reserve'])){
        $wdate = $_POST['datepicker'];
        $wtime = $_POST['time'];

        $wdate_array = array();
        $wtime_array = array();

        $insertDate=$conn->query("INSERT INTO date_tbl (date, time, ordertype) VALUES ('$wdate','$wtime',0)");

       $q=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM date_tbl");

       $dateRow=mysqli_num_rows($q);

           while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
               $wdate_array[]=$row['date'];
               $wtime_array[]=$row['time'];
           }
            if(array_intersect($wdate_array, $wtime_array)){
                echo "<p style='text-align:center;color:red;'><span class='fa fa-warning'></span> Date & Time Invalid!</p>";
            }else{
                echo "<p style='text-align:center;color:green;'><b></b> Date & Time are available!</p>";
            }
     }
?>
```

whenever i try to reserve it will only insert once and when i try again it doesn't insert anymore.

Comment: Don't use varchar to store dates.  RDBMS have date/datetime/timestamp fields for a reason.

Comment: Your `CREATE` statement doesn't match up with the columns in your `INSERT` statement

Comment: @PatrickQ Fixed it. I just added it a while ago forgot to add there

Comment: @Devon even if my input type is text. Can i insert them in a date/time fields?

Comment: "when i try again it doesn't insert anymore" When you try to insert the _same_ data again or when you try to insert _any_ data again?

Comment: @PatrickQ any data. If i use the same data again it also doesn't insert

Comment: You also have a syntax error. You are missing a closing double-quote at the end of your `echo` inside your `if` block. Are you actually copy-pasting your exact code or are you trying to transcribe it?

Comment: @PatrickQ oh yeah, i changed it cause my original code is much longer. It's suppose to insert another data under the else there.

Comment: If we don't know what your actual code is, it's going to be really hard to help you.

Comment: Sorry about that. I found another error on getting the value of the date and time. Fixed it again. That's pretty much what my code is i'm just having troubled with reserving the dates

Comment: Did you enable [error reporting?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/3828957), that may give away something more sever. Additionally the actual logic behind `if(array_intersect($wdate_array, $wtime_array)) {...}` seems flawed - afaik it will only be true if there is f.e. a time in both date/time arrays which should always be wrong, [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646142/what-does-it-mean-to-escape-a-string) is another issue - not for your current problem but - if you plan on something productive. Is the precondition `isset($_POST['reserve'])` met?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to store your Post value to a variable and use date field in your database.