# MYSQL query with quotes inside object

Tags: php, mysql

How can i put this query to work (it's giving error):

```
$result = "WHERE attributes like '%"{$GetMarca}"%' ";
```

I need the double quotes inside the single quotes because i'm searching inside a JSON field named attributes for specific value.

Comment: Use prepared queries instead.

Comment: This query is inside a specific framework, if i could avoid messing to much with the code i would be glad...

Comment: Set the value to another variable with the double quotes.

Comment: Again, **use prepared statements with placeholder values**. Can you be more specific about what framework you're using? Each one has a slightly different approach but the principle is the same. The goal here is to never introduce user data directly in the query. `WHERE attributes LIKE ?` and then bind that to`"%$GetMarca%"`.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte That's just making this already bad injection bug worse.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to escape your String.

```
$result = "WHERE attributes like '%\"" . $GetMarca . "\"%'";
```

The \ character escape the " character.

explained here in more detail for 'escape':
[What does it mean to escape a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646142/what-does-it-mean-to-escape-a-string)

Comment: This substitutes interpolation for concatenation which isn't necessary. If you're escaping for SQL it's also **extremely important** to use the proper MySQL escaping function which this does not do. Answers like this provide a superficial quick-fix but also create huge liabilities, so please, be very, very careful when giving this sort of advice.