# How to remove backslash at end of string?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am looping through a list of Discord guild names in node.js to generate a php file containing an array in the following format

```
<?php

$guildLookup = array( "164930842483761" => "guildName1",
"56334196291325" => "guildName2",
);

?>
```

One of the guild names is below

`/     text    \`

so when I insert it in the php array it looks like

```
<?php

$guildLookup = array( "164930842483761" => "guildName1",
"56334196291325" => "guildName2",
"56334196291342" => "/     text    \",
"56334196291135" => "guildName4",
);

?>
```

which generates the following error when trying to access php array.

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '487648187306475542' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ')'`

presumedly since the backslash escapes the " at end of the line.

I tried a couple of variations on the following in node.js to escape a backslash at end of a guild name or even getting rid of it before putting it in php file but can't seem to get it working. Appreciate any suggestions I can try.

```
var newString = orginalString.replace(/\\$/, '\\');
```

Comment: escape your slash

Comment: @anubhava The php file containing the array is created in node and written to server. I think the error prevents the file from even loading so I don't understand how I could use preg_quote?

Comment: @RisingSun I tried but can't seem to figure out the right regular expression to do so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean to escape a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646142/what-does-it-mean-to-escape-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'\\'` means `\`, you must replace with 4 `\\\\`, that's two escaped `\`

```
//Use 4 backslashes for \\
//Also remove the $ because escaped characters can be anywhere
var newString = orginalString.replace(/\\/, '\\\\');
```

Also, I suggest you validate for quotes.

```
var newString = orginalString.replace(/'/, "\\'");
```