# Replace double quotes and backslash \" in PHP

Tags: php, string

How to properly replace \ " or remove these chars from a string?
They must be taken together and not separately

```
$string = '{"ID":"89t9ZUIx1Mt","Title":"Pen","Attribution":"\"Pen\" by Jarlan Perez, https://poly.pizza/m/89t9ZUIx1Mt. Licence at https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0"';
$replaced = str_replace("\"\\", "",$string);
echo $replaced;
```

Result: `{"ID":"89t9ZUIx1Mt","Title":"Pen","Attribution":"Pen\" by Jarlan Perez, https://poly.pizza/m/89t9ZUIx1Mt. Licence at https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0"`

Goal:

```
{"ID":"89t9ZUIx1Mt","Title":"Pen","Attribution":"Pen by Jarlan Perez, https://poly.pizza/m/89t9ZUIx1Mt. Licence at https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0"
```

Comment: Something like `$replaced = str_replace("\"\\", "", $string);` ...

Comment: However, this smells a bit like an attempt to handle the symptom instead of curing the cause. Which rarely is a good idea ... Where do these escape sequences come from? Looks like data you got from some API probably. Wouldn't it make more sense to fix the data retrieval then? So that you have clean data from the beginning instead of having to try to clean the mess up later?

Comment: This does the job done, you're 100% right, unfortunately I'm not the owner of data source, it's an external API, haven't tried contacting owner yet tbh, any other way to handle this? I'm using this data in Js, and JSON Parse fails if "\ isn't handled

Comment: Or `$replaced = str_replace(' "\\', "", $string);` and remove the leading space as well

Comment: A backslash is used for escaping the next character, so it seems not logical to replace `"\\` (double-quote followed by back-slash) with an empty string

Comment: @PHPNewbie show the full data you're parsing from. It may be in a format that is easily parsed through some other method.

Comment: `{"ID":"89t9ZUIx1Mt","Title":"Pen","Attribution":"\"Pen\" by Jarlan Perez, https://poly.pizza/m/89t9ZUIx1Mt. Licence at https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0"`

Comment: Data seems to be fine except "\, @arkascha For some reason your solution only removes the first \ leaving ", while the second gets unchanged

Comment: @PHPNewbie that definitely reads like a JSON object, and it should be parseable by `JSON#parse` (or the php equivalent). Edit it into your question so newlines/etc are preserved normally, the escapes as they're placed should be fine. In the final string, they'll render as just `"`.

Comment: The value for `Attribution` should read `"Pen" by Jarlan Perez, http....`   Try to replace `\"` with `#`, and then check the results.

Comment: It should be `"Attribution":"Pen by Jarlan Perez long text"`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this JSON. You can simply ``json_decode($jsonStr, true);`` to get values.

Comment: I'd recommend using [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode) instead

Comment: Read the comments please, I need to prepare data for JavaScript, Json parse gives erros if "\ are kept, tested and confirmed

Comment: Take a look at updated main post, its \" instead of "\

Comment: Looks to me like you simply have your characters in the wrong order in the first argument to `str_replace()`. `"\"\\"` (quote first and then backslash) should be `"\\\""` (backslash first and then quote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$replaced = str_replace('\\"', '',$string);
```

Final solution

Comment: This should not replace anything, as there is no backslash followed by a double quote in the original string.

Comment: Please take a look at [What does it mean to escape a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646142/what-does-it-mean-to-escape-a-string)